# Why is Next Auth giving Client Fetch Error as soon as the page loads?

Tags: authentication, session, next.js, next-auth

I am following a utube tutorial to make a fullstack website. Using NextAuth for authentication. Using google providers. I am using the correct google id and secret. I have also added the callback url on console.cloud.google (callback url: http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google)

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'

const handler =  NextAuth(
    {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET
    }),
  ],

})

export {handler as GET, handler as POST}
```

The page.jsx

```
'use client'
import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react"

export default function Home() {

    const { data: session, status } = useSession();
    if(!session)   return (
      <main  className='bg-blue-900 w-screen h-screen flex items-center'>
      <div className="text-center w-full">
      <button className="bg-white p-4 rounded-lg" onClick={() => signIn()}>Login With Google</button>
      </div>
      </main>
    )

  return (
    <main  className='bg-blue-900 w-screen h-screen flex items-center'>
  <div>Logged In {session.user.email}</div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

I followed the exact steps of the person in the utube tutorial but my code's giving error. As soon as the page loads i get the following errors

My error:

[image]

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/auth/session not found
```

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/auth/log not found
```

```
app-index.js:34 [next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR]
```

```
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
```

When I click the button to log in, the url becomes http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error and the page shows the 404 not found error

I did face this similar issue a few weeks back, I solved it by looking it up on google but now I just can't seem to find the solution.
Initially, my env file did not have NEXTAUTH_URL and NEXTAUTH_URL_INTERNAL, so i added those but the error still did not go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was creating a [...nextauth].js file. This is not supported for Next js 13 App folder system. Creating api/[...nextauth]/route.js resolved the issue.